# Error: sql_mode=only_full_group_by in SQL (PHP)

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'KC_movies.tmdb_movies.movie_title'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

How to fix it?

This is my code:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT tmdb_movies.movie_title

,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genres.genres_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS genres

FROM tmdb_movies


JOIN genres ON genres.genres_tmdb_id=tmdb_movies.tmdb_id

  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT genres.genres_name FROM genres WHERE genres.genres_name = '$genres1');

 GROUP BY tmdb_movies.movie_title
```

Problem in code or I need to change SQL mode (how)?

Comment: This is a strange error, because the query you showed us doesn't appear to have this problem.  You are selecting and grouping by the `movie_title`, and you use a `GROUP_CONCAT()` call which is also allowed.  Are you sure this is the actual query which generated the error?

Comment: It is because of the `WHERE` line @TimBiegeleisen And i am 1000% sure

Comment: I somehow doubt this.  `WHERE` is supposed to be applied _before_ aggregation in `GROUP BY`.  So the full mode restriction should not be an issue there.  Can you setup a demo (www.rextester.com) with some sample data?

Comment: Your `exists` doesn't relate back to your main query. I wouldn't expect this error message, but you should correct it anyway.

Comment: Could you post the create statements for these tables, see if others can reproduce your problems?